# Can we play the same audio in two headsets connected to raspberry pi 3 via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

Can the same audio be played on 2 speakers already connected to raspberry pi 3?

Comment: Do you tried it?

Comment: ya..but v were unable to do it..

Comment: How do you tried it?